# How to save and load a NeuralFit model or weights?

Tags: python, parameters, neural-network, save, neuralfit

I have evolved a neural network to learn `y=x^2` using the [`neuralfit`](https://github.com/neural-fit/neuralfit) library, but I would like to save the model to do predictions later. I currently have:

```
import neuralfit
import numpy as np

# y(x) = x^2
x = np.arange(10).reshape(-1,1)
y = x**2

# Evolve model
model = neuralfit.Model(1,1)
model.compile('alpha', loss='mse', monitors=['size'])
model.evolve(x,y,epochs=1000)

# Save model
...
```

**How would I save and load `model`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this: (1) with Neuralfit and (2) with Keras. It is best to use NeuralFit because the resulting savefile is a lot smaller (50x in this case).

##### Method 1: with NeuralFit

Based on the [documentation](https://neuralfit.net/documentation/input-output/):

```py
# Save a model
model.save('model.nf')

# Load a saved model
model = neuralfit.load('model.nf')
```

##### Method 2: with Keras

Since NeuralFit allows conversion to Keras, we can convert the model to Keras and then save it using [their functionality](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize). In other words:

```py
# Save a model
keras_model = model.to_keras()
keras_model.save('model.h5')

# Load a saved model
keras_model = keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
model = neuralfit.from_keras(keras_model)
```